# Parsing full names from a list of names

Tags: python, parsing

I am using [namesparser](https://github.com/gwu-libraries/namesparser) to extract full names from a list of names.

```
from namesparser import HumanNames
names = HumanNames('Randy Heimerman, James Durham, Nate Green')
print(names.human_names[0])
```

Namesparser works well in most cases, but the above example is getting hung up. I believe it is because the name "Randy" includes "and", which namesparser is treating as a separator.

When I move Randy's name to the end of the string, the correct name is printed (James Durham). If I try to print either of the 2 other names, though, the wrong strings are returned.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide what is the current output that you get?

Comment: Are all the full names literally comma separated? Also, have you considered using a named entity recognition pipeline? Stanford's CoreNLP would parse this no sweat, and then you'd just use while loops to collect consecutive tokens with the person attribute...

Comment: whats `HumanNames` I don't see that class in the docs, only `HumanName` which takes one person at a time, if you could provide more info there is probably a way already how to do this in the library

Comment: https://github.com/gwu-libraries/namesparser

Comment: the issue is here -> https://github.com/gwu-libraries/namesparser/blob/master/namesparser.py#L69 you'll have to change that line otherwise it will keep splitting the name on the `and`

Comment: @aws_apprentice Thanks! I think that should do it. I changed `split_names = re.split(" ?(and|,| ) ?", names_str)` to `split_names = re.split(" ?(and(?=\s)|,| ) ?", names_str)` so that it only splits if the and is followed by white space. Testing it out now!

Comment: See if there is an existing issue for this on GitHub. If not, submit one. It probably should only split on `and` surrounded by whitespace. That said, this makes one wonder how well tested/widely used the library is. If you're only using it for yourself, then that's fine, but if this is going into a production app, I'd be hesitant to use it.

Comment: Also, that's the wrong repository. The correct one is linked on the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/nameparser/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the comma `,` as your delimiter.

```
def print_names( name_string ):
    return (name.strip() for name in name_string.split(","))
```

what this does is split your string on the comma, and then strip trailing and leading spaces, etc... before returning an array of names.

Now that you have a generator of names, you can pass it into other things for example:

```
humans = [HumanName(name) for name in print_names(name_string)]
```

but then again, I dont know what your class HumanNames / HumanName really means, and you didnt put a class defition.

If you are looking at this module: https://pypi.org/project/nameparser/ in which it takes a string consisting of a singular name, the above will still work no problem.

Comment: I can't simply split based on comma because of names like "John Smith, Jr." Namesparser is supposed to account for these situations (and in fact, works well). It just seems to be getting tripped up by this scenario where "and" falls within the name itself.

Comment: I think you need to point me to a class which defines "HumanNames" because HumanName takes only 1.  I dont know what the constraints are for the plural version. Can you link it?  I should be able to assist a bit more if i can see its implementation